# ADLS connectivity from Linux server using Azure CLI

Tags: linux, azure-cli, rhel7, iics

Does anyone established ADLS connection from linux machine using Azure CLI. Ofcourse we can do this from portal but the idea is to establish from IICS secure agent, which in turn a RHEL server.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is **no CLI commands** to establish ***ADLS Connections from Linux Machine***.

You can use the Portal or Programming languages (Python, C#, & other)

#### Reference

- [ADLS connect using Service principal python](https://amalgjose.com/2021/04/22/python-program-connect-to-azure-adls-gen2-using-service-principle/)
- [ADLS ODBC connect using python Linux](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/azuredatalake-odbc-python-linux.rst)
- [Access DataLake using Managed Identity (API)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-linux-vm-access-datalake)